# Accept Partial Payments on Android and IOS App

Tags: android, paypal, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

Hello I have a requirement where a customer opens an the app and selects a service provider for a certain service. Each service provider has their own pricing for the service they are providing.

What i need to do is when the customer selects a service provider and agrees to the price, the customer has to deposit 50% of the fee upfront. The customer also enters the date on when the service is required.,

After the service is complete on the specified date, the remaining 50% is charged.

With some of the popular payment gateways out there, there doesnt seem to be a solution to this. I have seen subscription based solutions, but this is really just one extra charge in the future.

Can anyone recommend a vendor that could possible meet the requirment?

If it's possible to future date the transaction for the remaining 50% can this date be modified or cancelled if needed?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Payments can only be captured once, so you if you do a partial capture, you lose the hold on the remaining funds.  The solution is to set this up as two separate charges. You could capture one immediately, and capture the second when the service is complete. This does put a hold for the total amount on the customer's card.

Also, charges automatically release if they aren't captured in 7 days, so you may have to recreate the extra charge if it has expired already.